# How to Create Weight Based Shipping Rule

Tags: shipping

Right now I am using `Flat Shipping` rates. I want to implement below rule

```
up to 500gms - INR 100
501 to 1000gms - INR 50
1001 to 1500gms -INR 200
1501 to 2000gms - INR 250 and so on...
```

Is there any way to set this rule ?

Comment: which Magento version ?

Comment: I am Using 2.2.6 - community edition. I don't want to add/calculate distance in this rule.

Comment: If this is not possible, can we restrict cart based on weight? Ex. User only allowed to add up to 2000gms of products.

Comment: it is possible, See my answer and let me know if have any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Table Rates` shipping method instead of `Flat Shipping`.

> Go to Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Methods

Switch to `Store View` to `website`

Now enable `Table Rates` and choose **Condition**:  **Weight vs. Destination**

Final Settings will be:

[image]

Now **Export** Sample CSV and add your actual data like:

[image]

Now clear cache and see result on front-end

Hope above will help!

Comment: Hello Pawan, Thanks for the solution. It worked for me. Cheers.

Comment: Great! You can accept answer and upvote

Comment: Just one correction. Change weight to KG Ex. 0.501, 0.1001, 0.1501 as Magento excepts value in kg. Else for Magento 501 is 501KG.

Comment: you can adjust as per your requirement, this is a general solution. please do needful thing if answer helped you!

Comment: @NirajNagar, You can accept answer, So it will be beneficial for other users too.

Comment: Hello All, I am using Magento 2.3.5. I am trying to implement weight-based shipping. This is my old question. I don't find the export and import .csv file. Please guide.

Comment: @NirajNagar, you need to change scope from "Default config" to website